# SVG <use> element not visible in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, cross-browser

I have an SVG element that is embedded into my HTML page that works perfectly on Firefox but does not work on Chrome.

I'm using a mask to cover a video background while the SVG element has a transparent fill (using CSS class on use element) to show video background through it.

I believe I identified the problem to be with the `<use>` tag because when I inspect it in Chrome, the `use` element has some dimensions but is not matching the SVG viewbox's size: `<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300" class="svg-inverted-mask">` that it lives in. In Firefox, the size of `use` element matches the viewbox and renders correctly.

Code:

```html
<div class="wrap heightwrap wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300" class="svg-defs">
    <!-- Symbol with Logo -->
      <symbol id="s-text2">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="30%" y="-25%" width="700" height="800" viewBox="0 0 1000 800">
            <defs>
              <rect id="a" x="50%" y="50%" width="612" height="792"/>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="b">
              <use href="#a" overflow="visible"/>
            </clipPath>
            <path clip-path="url(#b)" d="M468.896,118.65l-80.667,254.289H145.563l-24.334-62.667h188 c0,0,26.167,0.167,33.311-18.676l15.356-50.99c20.333-62.333,22.67-67.217-34-67.667c-15.121-0.12-30.689,0.122-39.254,0.072 c-17.878-0.105-22.246,0.139-20.368-10.094l10.712-34.979c0,0,1.285-9.287,17.66-9.287"/>
            <path clip-path="url(#b)" d="M275.563,267.9c28.667,0,28.013-1.13,35.833-28.5c8-28,9.457-29.082-12-29.5 c-10.548-0.205-26.166,0-26.166,0c-51.959,0-64.834,1.5-58.222-24.03c2.682-10.354,6.587-25.693,12.221-45.637 c4.024-14.247,8.103-29.353,11.369-38.006C250.481,70.74,271.842,75.708,343.23,75.9c92.334,0.249,139.333,0,139.333,0l20.333-62 h-314l-41.553,149.031c0,0-2.537,10.65-6.408-0.212L87.896,13.9h-69l89.667,254H275.563"/>
        </svg>
      </symbol>
    <!-- Mask with text -->
      <mask id="m-text2" maskunits="userSpaceOnUse" maskcontentunits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" class="mask__shape">
        </rect>
        <use href="#s-text2" class="mask__text"></use>
      </mask>
   </svg>

   <div class="box-with-text">
   <!-- Container for video -->
   <div class="text-fill">
   <video class="video" src="/css/fractal3.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
  </div>
  <!-- Visible SVG -->
   <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300" class="svg-inverted-mask">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#m-text2)" class="shape--fill" />
      <use href="#s-text2" class="text--transparent"></use>
    </svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the unnecessary clipPaths seems to help.

They look like the sort of clips that Illustrator adds to reproduce its way of rendering strokes.  But since your symbol doesn't have an stroking, they are safe to remove.

```html
<div class="wrap heightwrap wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300" class="svg-defs">
    <!-- Symbol with Logo -->
      <symbol id="s-text2">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="30%" y="-25%" width="700" height="800" viewBox="0 0 1000 800">
            <path d="M468.896,118.65l-80.667,254.289H145.563l-24.334-62.667h188 c0,0,26.167,0.167,33.311-18.676l15.356-50.99c20.333-62.333,22.67-67.217-34-67.667c-15.121-0.12-30.689,0.122-39.254,0.072 c-17.878-0.105-22.246,0.139-20.368-10.094l10.712-34.979c0,0,1.285-9.287,17.66-9.287"/>
            <path d="M275.563,267.9c28.667,0,28.013-1.13,35.833-28.5c8-28,9.457-29.082-12-29.5 c-10.548-0.205-26.166,0-26.166,0c-51.959,0-64.834,1.5-58.222-24.03c2.682-10.354,6.587-25.693,12.221-45.637 c4.024-14.247,8.103-29.353,11.369-38.006C250.481,70.74,271.842,75.708,343.23,75.9c92.334,0.249,139.333,0,139.333,0l20.333-62 h-314l-41.553,149.031c0,0-2.537,10.65-6.408-0.212L87.896,13.9h-69l89.667,254H275.563"/>
        </svg>
      </symbol>
    <!-- Mask with text -->
      <mask id="m-text2" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" class="mask__shape">
        </rect>
        <use href="#s-text2" class="mask__text"></use>
      </mask>
   </svg>

   <div class="box-with-text">
   <!-- Container for video -->
   <div class="text-fill">
   <video class="video" src="/css/fractal3.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
  </div>
  <!-- Visible SVG -->
   <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300" class="svg-inverted-mask">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#m-text2)" class="shape--fill" />
      <use href="#s-text2" class="text--transparent"></use>
    </svg>
   </div>
</div>
```